# Writing List to a csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

I'm currently using Python v2.10.  I'm having trouble writing data to a csv file.  Wondering if someone might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong.  I'm getting the following error: `"TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"` - not sure how to correct this.  Also, I thought to write to a csv file, the data must be in string format ?

Ideally I would like each row to be like:
Name, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3

Here is the code I have:

```
import csv

def main():
    my_coords = open('Geo_Coords.csv', 'a')
    coords = csv.reader(my_coords)

    how_many = raw_input("How many Geometries do you wish to enter? ")
    counter = 0
    coords = []

    while counter < how_many:
        geometry = raw_input("Geometry Name  ")
        first_coordE = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Easting) ")
        first_coordN = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Northing) ")
        sec_coordE = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Easting) ")
        sec_coordN = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Northing) ")
        third_coordE = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Easting) ")
        third_coordN = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Northing) ")
        counter = counter + 1

        my_coords.write(coords[[geometry],[first_coordE,first_coordN], [sec_coordE,sec_coordN], [third_coordE,third_coordN]] )

    my_coords.close()
    print my_coords

main()
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the line `coords[[geometry],[first_coordE,first_coordN], [sec_coordE,sec_coordN], [third_coordE,third_coordN]]`. You're creating a tuple `[geometry],[first_coordE,first_coordN], [sec_coordE,sec_coordN], [third_coordE,third_coordN]`, then using that to index the list `coords`. What were you trying to do with that tuple/list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code contains some issues, you reassign coords as a list before that it was an `csv` object, you are using `csv.reader` instead of `csv.writer`, I encourage you to read the documentation there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Maybe this could help you, I keep the structure you use, I just modified a little bit.

```
import csv

def main():
    with open('Geo_Coords.csv', 'a') as my_coords:
        coords = csv.writer(my_coords)

        how_many = int(raw_input("How many Geometries do you wish to enter? "))
        # TODO: Check user input
        rows = []

        for _ in range(how_many):
            geometry = raw_input("Geometry Name  ")
            first_coordE = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Easting) ")
            first_coordN = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Northing) ")
            sec_coordE = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Easting) ")
            sec_coordN = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Northing) ")
            third_coordE = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Easting) ")
            third_coordN = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Northing) ")

            rows.append([geometry, first_coordE,
                         first_coordN, sec_coordE,
                         sec_coordN, third_coordE,
                         third_coordN])

        coords.writerows(rows)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

def main():
    my_coords = open('Geo_Coords.csv', 'a')
    coords = csv.reader(my_coords)
```

OK, `coords` is the name of a `csv.reader()` object

```
    how_many = raw_input("How many Geometries do you wish to enter? ")
```

and `how many` is the name of a string, say `"15"`

```
    counter = 0
    coords = []
```

here you do a strange thing, `coords` is now the name of an empty list and the `csv.reader()` has no more a name that references it...

```
    while counter < how_many:
```

also the above statement is strange... you are comparing an int with a string! in Python 2 the logical expression `string < integer` is always `True`!

```
        geometry = raw_input("Geometry Name  ")
        first_coordE = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Easting) ")
        first_coordN = raw_input("1st Co-ord (Northing) ")
        sec_coordE = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Easting) ")
        sec_coordN = raw_input("2nd Co-ord (Northing) ")
        third_coordE = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Easting) ")
        third_coordN = raw_input("3rd Co-ord (Northing) ")
        counter = counter + 1
```

so far, so good — but note that you've not modified the value of `coords`, and hence when you'll use the name `coords` you are just referencing an empty list

```
        my_coords.write(coords[[geometry],[first_coordE,first_coordN], [sec_coordE,sec_coordN], [third_coordE,third_coordN]] )
```

and here you are, referencing, by addressing, the content of an empty list; further, the syntax of the addressing is wrong, it must be either an integer or a *slice object* — further, the `.write(...)` method expects a string and you are trying, afaict, to write a list of strings at once...

```
    my_coords.close()
    print my_coords
```

This will print something like

```
<closed file 'Geo_Coords.csv', mode 'a' at 0x7efc8946a540>
```

---

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37086759/2749397) by [Koffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3461734/koffee) seems totally adequate to me, so I recommend that you accept it and possibly upvote it.

Comment: Good and complete explanation @gboffi (y)

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ rolled back your edit because the further indent is not an error, it _exactly_ reflects the _correct_ indentatation of OP's code.

Comment: Excuse me! I see now that you have explained the code part by part, so your indentation makes it simply better. Sorry that I didn't notice that before. And thank you for notifying me of that!